# React child component not reacting to state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to break down my example to keep it simple.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import FeedColumnActionsNewPost from './FeedColumnActionsNewPost';
import FeedColumnActionsNewDogAction from './FeedColumnActionsNewDogAction';

class FeedColumnActions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.toggleAction = this.toggleAction.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      new_action: this.props.new_action,
      new_post: "",
      new_dogAction: this.props.new_dog_action,
      new_dogActionClass: ""
    }
  }
  toggleAction(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-name'));
    if(e.target.getAttribute('data-name') == "newPost" && e.target.getAttribute("class") != "active"){
      this.setState({
        new_post: "active",
        new_action: !this.state.new_action
      });
    }else if(e.target.getAttribute('data-name') == "newPost" && e.target.getAttribute("class") == "active"){
      this.setState({
        new_post: "",
        new_action: !this.state.new_action
      });
    }else if(e.target.getAttribute('data-name') == "newDogAction" && e.target.getAttribute("class") != "active"){
      this.setState({
        new_dogActionClass: "active",
        new_dogAction: !this.state.new_dogAction
      });
    }else if(e.target.getAttribute('data-name') == "newDogAction" && e.target.getAttribute("class") == "active"){
      this.setState({
        new_dogActionClass: "",
        new_dogAction: !this.state.new_dogAction
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    var that = this;
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="feed-action-box">
          <ul className="feed-action-bar">
            <li>
              <button onClick={this.toggleAction} className={this.state.new_post} data-name="newPost">
                <i data-name="newPost" className="fa fa-plus"></i>
                <span data-name="newPost">New Post</span>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button onClick={this.toggleAction} className={this.state.new_dogActionClass} data-name="newDogAction" id="newDogAction">
                <i data-name="newDogAction" className="fa fa-paw"></i>
                <span data-name="newDogAction">New Dog Action</span>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        { this.state.new_action ? <FeedColumnActionsNewPost /> : '' }

        { this.state.new_dogAction ? <FeedColumnActionsNewDogAction /> : '' }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FeedColumnActions;
```

So I have this child-component which receives its state via props from the master component.
When the user clicks the button to activate a new action then the state gets updated properly and the child-component `<FeedColumnActionsNewPost />` gets displayed immediately. That child-component contains a form -> the content gets sent to the whole master component and when the form is being submitted the master component sets `new_action: false`.

When I inspect the whole process in React Tools the master component passes the new state down to the child component correctly. And the child components state gets changed to :false instantly.

Although the state is now false again this line doesn't seem to fire:

```
{ this.state.new_action ? <FeedColumnActionsNewPost /> : '' }
```

Therefore this component stays visible.

Any ideas why the change of a does not affect this line?

Comment: This was just asked yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

If you derive any `state` from your `props`, you likely need to implement the [`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method on your component.

Trivially, this would just be `this.setState(nextProps)`, which would overwrite any local state with incoming props.

Or, you could pick and choose: `this.setState({ new_action: nextProps.new_action })`, etc.

Comment: I have to upvote your answer because it indeed triggers the state change on prop change. Is there a way to make componentWillReceiveProps IGNORE all object elements except one? Because with that way I receive a huge lag because the whole props chunk is being "scanned" everytime it changes

Comment: I don't understand your question. The lifecycle method is called with the same props, whether you implement it or not.

Comment: I have a custom script with which you can reposition some picture within a container. This script pushes the position state to the master component which updates its state then again pushes it down as prop to the component where the picture is being displayed. So if you move your mouse / finger to reposition it it gets triggered quite often and starts lagging if I implement the funciton

Comment: even with just: `this.setState({ new_action: nextProps.new_action })`?

Comment: Yes. Thats how I handled it within the componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) function.